# dot product of (n,) shaped arrays to give an n by n array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say you have an array `X` of shape `(n,)`,

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
X = np.random.rand(n)
```

and you want to make the following dot product **XX^T** (by **X^T** I mean the transpose of **X**). The result should give an n by n matrix. However using

```
np.dot(X, X.T)
```

will give a scalar. It's like if it does **X^T X** instead. Unless you do the following

```
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], 1))
np.dot(X, X.T)
```

Is there a way to do it without having to reshape the numpy vector?

Comment: `np.einsum('i,j', X, X)`

Comment: If `x` is (10,) shape, `x.T` is the same.  `T` switches dimensions; it doesn't add one.  `np.dot(x,x.)` is a scalar inner.dot product.  `x[:,None]*x` produces a (10,10).  Repeat after me: "reshape is my friend"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both a and b are 1-D arrays, `numpy.dot(a, b)` returns the inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).

You can use the [`numpy.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) function instead:

```
np.outer(X, X)
```